# how can i get android_webview_java.jar, webviewchromium.so from chromium？

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, webkit, chromium

I want to use android `webView` in my project,but it do not have many features about HTML5, so I want to build a `android webView` from chromium project. After I get the depot_tools, how can I get `android webView.jar` and `webViewChromium.so` from the chromium?

```
~/chromium/src$ ninja -C out/Release android_webview_apk
~/chromium/src$ build/android/adb_install_apk.py --apk AndroidWebView.apk --apk_package org.chromium.android_webview.shell --release
```